# Fargate container_definition field "secretOptions" not passsing datadog API_KEY to logConfiguration

Tags: terraform, aws-fargate, datadog, aws-secrets-manager, firelens

I'm trying to send my ECS Fargate logs to Datadog. To do this I need to pass my Datadog API_KEY as a field in the `logConfiguration` object. I need to secure my API_KEY so I am using AWS Secrets Manager via the `secretOptions` key of the `logConfiguration` object.

I'm following the steps from AWS laid out [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-secrets.html#secrets-logconfig).
The full steps from the Datadog site can be found [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/ecs_fargate/?tab=fluentbitandfirelens#log-collection)

For some reason I dont see the logs show up in datadog. Here is the log config section of my Terraform code under the `container_definitions` object of the `aws_ecs_task_definition` resource:

```
"logConfiguration": {
    "logDriver": "awsfirelens",
    "options": {
        "Name": "datadog",
        "Host": "http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com",
        "dd_service": "myservice",
        "dd_source": "mysource",
        "dd_message_key": "log",
        "dd_tags": "env:dev",
        "TLS": "on",
        "provider": "ecs"
    },
    "secretOptions": [{
        "name": "apikey",
        "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:secret:mysecret"
                }]
}
```

If I take out the `secretOptions` and add the apikey in plaintext, the logs show up on the datadog console:

```
"logConfiguration": {
   "logDriver": "awsfirelens",
   "options": {
       "Name": "datadog",
       "Host": "http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com",
       "dd_service": "myservice",
       "dd_source": "mysource",
       "dd_message_key": "log",
       "dd_tags": "env:dev",
       "TLS": "on",
       "provider": "ecs",
       "apikey": "myapikey"
   }
}
```

I of course cant just send my API_KEY in plaintext. Does the `secretOptions` just not work for Datadog? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At least the documentation suggests it: "Use a TaskDefinition secret to avoid exposing the apikey in plain text."

[Datadog documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/ecs_fargate/?tab=fluentbitandfirelens)

Works like a charm here. Same configuration used with Terraform 0.15.3 and AWS Provider 3.41.0